# PHP Accessing property containing *

Tags: php

i am returned an array that looks like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#176 (1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

when var_dump() is executed.

So how would i acceess the count object?

Its

```
$result[0]->COUNT(*)
```

but this results in an error?

```
$result[0]->{COUNT(*)}
```

does not help either.

Comment: Modify your SQL query to return that value with an alias

Answer (score 7):

Use brackets:

```
echo $data->{'COUNT(*)'};
```

But it's about SQL and I recommend to give an alias to your field, like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS records_count FROM t
```